# Using Telnet on windows is taking an awfully long time. Is it common for this to happen?

Tags: windows, telnet

I'm trying to access some websites via **Telnet** on **Windows XP** and whenever I open a website or my `127.0.0.1` on port 80 it echoes back `connecting to 127.0.0.1 ...` or whatever other target I have typed.

After a long long time the connection times out and I'm left with nothing.

My browser works fine.

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you type `GET /` after the `connecting...` string? It could be that you've connected and your telnet client isn't telling you, and the webserver's waiting for you to do something.

Comment: exactly like that? All caps, whitespace then a slash?

Comment: @Felipe: Yep. That's what your web browser sends to the server. It's a request to get whatever's at the root of the filesystem (i.e. if you telnetted to google.com, it'd get you the same page that you'd get if you used Chrome to browse to google.com (javascript DOM manipulation notwithstanding)).

Comment: Oh yeah...On google and on my remote website it works... But when i try 127.0.0.1 and the GET / it complains : Undefined index: HTTP_HOST

Comment: My last question is out of scope I guess. U answered my main question so it's green tick to you

Comment: GET / is HTTP 0.9, which your local website might not support. If you want to speak HTTP 1.0, you'll need at least two lines, GET / HTTP/1.0 and Host: 127.0.0.1 (or whatever host name you are telnetting to). You might want to try using curl or wget instead.